# Unable to connect Database to HTML form

Tags: php, html, database

Well I build a form in html but I am unable to connect and collect data from the form to a database. Here is the code I used to connect and collect data from the form.

The HTML form -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4eL9qVqrm2OOWpMZmV1dUlNbTg/view?usp=sharing

The PHP connect file ->
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4eL9qVqrm2OY2pDR09nb0w5bE0/view

The PHP database file ->
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4eL9qVqrm2OeU5IdVMxVHBkaVk/view

It returns the code back on clicking submit.

```
    <?php include 'NENDatabase.php';?>

<?php
$Your_name=$_POST['Your_Name'];
$email=$_POST['Your_Email_ID'];
$Message=$_POST['Type_your_Message'];
$Gender=$_POST['sex'];

mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO Visitors(Your_Name,Your_Email_ID,Message,sex)
                VALUES('$Your_name','$email','$Message','$Gender')");
if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0){
    echo "<p>People visited</p>";
    echo "<a href="index.html">Go Back</a>";
} else {
    echo "People Added<br />";
    echo mysqli_error ($connect);
}               
?>
```

I have no idea about collecting data into databases and used the php codes from tutorials online. Still the code doesn't run. Any help or push in the right direction will be very helpful.

Comment: Have you connected to your database using a tool like phpmyadmin to ensure the username and password are correct?

Comment: yeah I used it too but still no success

Comment: What error are you getting? You should update your 3rd file above to include error notification. Currently you only have it echo "Failed to connect"   Update it to ' echo "Connection to DB failed" . mysqli_connect_error(); '   This will tell you the error and help us help you.

Comment: @m1xolyd1an it simply returns the php code on clicking submit.

Comment: @Geniusknight  did you add mysqli_connect_error();  ?

Comment: @m1xolyd1an yup you should see the changes in a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

**Found two errors**

Error 1 - change form method to post, because php code uses $_POST

Error 2

```
mysqli_query($connect"INSERT INTO Visitors(Your_Name,Your_Email_ID,Message,sex)
                VALUES('$Your_name','$email','$Message','$Gender')");
```

function parameters not seperated by comma, so change it to

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO Visitors(Your_Name,Your_Email_ID,Message,sex)
                VALUES('$Your_name','$email','$Message','$Gender')");
```

Comment: your server? or localhost?

Comment: hmm I have no idea about it ! @Unni I just added the codes but I have no idea about server part. Please tell me how to add one.

Comment: alright I got it ! I was running all this time on windows local urls instead of localhost server. I just had to change the url line to localhost/file.php. :D

Answer (score 0):

Hmm the problem was not with the code but with the url path that I was using. I just had to change the paths to localhost/filename.php or localhost/site.html so that it is actually hosted and run on the localhost server. You can also use absolute servers instead of localhost. (And make sure all your files are in HTACCESS folder under xampp directory of mysql)